# Git now wont stop showing hundreds of untracked files and dirs everytime i git status

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm not sure what I did, deleted a repo and I must have changed a config in the process. Every time (no matter what directory I'm in) I do a git status, im now seeing hundreds of files and directories that have nothing to do with my current working directory or with git period. How can I clear all of these? I have tried what I have seen recommended so far (git status -uno, git ls-files --others --exclude-standard >> .gitignore). Nothing will clear them - I can't do a git checkout on any of them either since none of them are even associated with git.

Example of what im getting in my console:

```
    Untracked files:
    (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    ../../../.Trash/
    ../../../.adobe/
    ../../../.atom/
    ../../../.babel.json
    ../../../.bash_history
    ../../../.bash_profile
    ../../../.bash_profile.pysave
    ../../../.bash_sessions/
    ../../../.bashrc.save
    ../../../.composer/
    ../../../.config/
    ../../../.cups/
    ../../../.dropbox/
    ../../../.electron/
    ../../../.git-credentials
    ../../../.gitconfig
    ../../../.heroku/
    ../../../Documents/
    ../../../Downloads/
    ../../../Dropbox/
    ../../../Library/
    ../../../Movies/
    ../../../Music/
    ../../../Pictures/
    ../../../Sites/
    ../../../Sti_Trace.log
    ../../../index.html
    ../../../npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Run `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to see *where* the Git repository is. It looks to me like it's your home directory.

Comment: seeing this in every directory - home or within project files

Comment: That would mean, as I suggested, that your Git repository is (in) your home directory. You probably don't want that; you probably want a repository, or multiple repositories, within a / each project.

Comment: If I did init a a repo in a non project directory/top level.. it was a mistake, for sure dont want that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a .git repo initiated in your root directory.

I'd go into your root, do:

```
ls -a | grep .git
```

And see if this shows up:

```
.git/
.gitignore
```

If so, you'd just want to do rm -rf *.git/, although I'd be very careful since rm -rf has the potential to nuke your root!

Comment: nothing back after running `ls -a | grep .git` in my root

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to **show hidden files, folders, and drives**.

Then delete the `.git` folder (hidden folder) which  you don’t want.